# Use non-nullable reference types in DTO:s/api objects

Tags: c#, non-nullable, jsonconvert

I want to use non-nullable reference type in my dto:s/api objects, without getting warnings and without defeating the entire purpose by using them by using the bang operator.

Lets say I consume from an GraphQL-endpoints that returns a hierarchy of complex objects. So normally I just deserialize the response with a type parameter...something like this

```
var customerInfo = mySerializer.Deserialize<CustomerInfo>(jsonResponseFromServer)
```

From the schema-file I have a guarantee that some of these objects and strings (inside CustomerInfo) are **not** null.

so I want to use non-nullable reference types in my DTOs. But now I get complaints about all these non-nullable properties, because the compiler has no clue about the GraphQL-scheme.

I'd really want to avoid writing humongous constructor for all these objects and If I did I wouldn't know how to get my serializer to use those anyway...

This must be a quite common problem, but I haven't found any recommended solution

**Edit, from a comment:** about the structure of my class, lets keep it simple, because the exact structure is not relevant

```
public class CustomerInfo
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Address Address {get;set;}
    //...  
}
```

So...nothing special.

Comment: the graph-scheme is - as already mentioned - completely irrelevant to your compiler. What matters is your class-structure, which you didn't provide and which therefor makes it very hard for us to understand your issues. Generally the compiler can just verify your **source-code**, so that code must reflect all constraints and all the validation-rules that apply to your scheme.

Comment: This is nothing special, but I updated the question, I might misunderstand you. I have a class with some properties, some of them is guaranteed not to be null

Comment: Yes, Im fine with doing explicit validation on incoming objects (on the props that cant be null)...but good point. Im just trying to minimize the ?. all over the place

Answer (score 1):

Non-nullable reference type is a syntactic addition which is only used in static code analysis, where compiler tries to prove that a `null` assignment is not attempted on a reference.

As mentioned in the comment, this has nothing to do with the GraphQL, nor with deserialization. It is entirely a C# question.

Another related issue is that there is no runtime check whether a `null` reference is assigned or not. Therefore, my first concern is in using non-nullable reference types in a DTO in the first place - what is the purpose of that if, at runtime, that reference can be set to `null` none the less, probably causing a `NullReferenceException` downstream that was not supposed to happen.

And, finally, the direct answer to the question. If a type declares fields or properties of non-nullable types, then for each of those, one of these must be present in code to avoid warnings:

1. Set to a non-`null` value in the constructor,
2. Initialized to a non-`null` value using the initializer syntax, or
3. Initialized to a `null!` to mark the intention to set to a non-null value later.

Regarding your particular design with DTOs, be warned that any non-nullable reference type could effectively be set to `null` later, should the data you are deserializing change in the future. You should still provide a constructor which guards against `null` inputs.

Comment: What would a constructor that guards against null inputs look like?

Comment: That constructor's arguments would be nullable, like public SomeClass(string? x, string? y);
The member variables would be non-nullable, though.